# Usar Plugins jQuery en Angular MVC

Tags: angular, mvc

Tengo varios plugins de jQuery que quiero utilizar en mi componente Angular, pero no he podido de la forma tradicional, agregando la referencia en el index y llamandolo en el component.html como:

```html
<script> $('#id').plugin()) </script>
```

Necesito saber como puedo hacerlo sin tener que buscar el plugins npm para instalar ya que algunos están limitados.

Por ejemplo, el plugins DataTable y fullCalendar son algunos.

Saludos !

Comment: angular tiene componentes que pueden sustituir a cada uno de los usados en jquery, es mejor que investigues y lo reemplaces , asi no mezclaras tantas librerias.

Answer (score 0):

utilizar jQuery en Angular no es muy bien visto algunos lo llegan a conciderar código "sucio". sin embargo si insistes en utilizarlo podrías:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

[...]

    ngOnInit() { 
        $(‘button’).click(function() { 
            alert(‘hola jquery’); 
        }); 
    }
```

para importar debes primero haber instalado jquery por medio de node:

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Reitero, hay muchísimos componentes que sustituyen estos que ocupas con jquery.
https://material.angular.io/components/table
https://github.com/Swimlane/angular-data-table

etc...

Comment: No pregunto como usar jQuery, eso ya lo incorporé al proyecto, lo que quiero es usar plugins de jQuery, como DataTable(), Validator.js, etc... en mi componente angular.